# std::fstream doesn't create file

Tags: c++, stl, fstream

I am trying to use std::fstream for io to file, and I want to create the file if it doesn't already exist.

```
  std::fstream my_stream
  my_stream.open("my_file_name",std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
  if(!my_stream)
      std::cout<<"error"<<strerror(errorno);
```

I get this result:
         "No such file or directory."

How can I create the file in this case?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You're specifying `std::fstream::in` in your call to [fstream::open()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open). This is [known](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-361639.html) to force it to require an existing file.

Either remove `std::fstream::in` from your `mode` argument, or specify `std::fstream::trunc` in addition to the other flags.

Comment: And noting that `trunc` creates an empty file each time.

Comment: But what, if I wnat to open for reading and writing and to create the file, if it doesn not exist? Standard libc `open()` can do that by specifying the`O_CREAT` flag. Is that not possible in C++?

Answer (score 15):

It's a little messy but works. Doesn't overwrite the file if it exists but creates a new one if the first open fails.

```
std::fstream my_stream
my_stream.open("my_file_name",std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);

if(!my_stream)
{
    my_stream.open("my_file_name",std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::trunc | std::fstream::out);    
    my_stream.close();
    // re-open with original flags
    my_stream.open("my_file_name",std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
}
else
{
    // read something
} 

// read/write here
```

Comment: You can remove that second close(). Simply opening it with the flags "binary | in | out | trunc" will work fine.

Comment: Very late on this, but, couldn't

my_stream.open("my_file_name",std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::trunc | std::fstream::out);

simply be

my_stream.open("my_file_name", std::ios::out);

?
It's just meant to create the file momentarily...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the reference from [std::basic_filebuf::open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)

If you use `out|in` which is the default mode, it is equivalent to using `r+` as access mode in `fopen`, so it cannot create a new file.

So if you want to create a `fstream` that can read and write a new file, you can use `in|out|trunc` as `w+`

And you can create or write to end if file exists by using `in|app` or `in|out|app` as `a+`