# fstream not creating new file

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I am trying to learn dynamic file access. My code is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    dtbrec xrec; // class object
    fstream flh;

    // Doesn't create a new file unless ios::trunc is also given.
    flh.open("database.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    flh.seekp(0,ios::end);
    xrec.getdata();
    flh.write((char*)&xrec, sizeof(dtbrec));

    flh.close();
}
```

I thought that `fstream` by default creates a new file 'database.txt' if it doesn't exist. Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835888/stdfstream-doesnt-create-file?rq=1

Comment: @ThomWiggers wow, thank you but if ios::in is not specified how is the data stored in the file?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie thankyou, i have an idea on how to use ifstream and outstream, but wanted to use fstream

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some pointers about fstream:

a. If you are using a back slash to specify the directory such as when using
fstream f;

> *f.open( "folder\file", ios::out);*

it won't work, a back slash has to be preceded by a backslash, so the correct way would be:

> *f.open( "folder\\file", ios::out);*

b. If you want to create a new file, this won't work:

> *f.open("file.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);*

the correct way would be to first create the file, using either ios::out or ios::trunc

> *f.open("file.txt". ios::out)  or f.open("file.txt", ios::trunc);*

and then

> *f.open("file.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);*

c. Finally, it could be in this order as specified in this answer,
[fstream not creating file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835888/stdfstream-doesnt-create-file)

Basically ios::in requires to already have an existing file.

Comment: Your examples show forward slashes, not backslashes. You do not need to escape forward slashes.

Comment: Thanks Buge I have edited it, I used backlash when I was learning about fstream. While I am aware and predominantly using forward slash now, I will not like to edit the content (using backslashes) as I personally believe that initially while learning fstream, this post may be useful especially to a newbie, however your comment can prove  useful to them as well

Answer (score 5):

Try using `ofstream`, it automatically creates a file, if it does not already exist. Or, if you want to do both input, and output on the stream, try using `fstream`, but you need not specify `ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary`, because `fstream` automatically sets it up for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Stephen Jacob said, I found that I needed to do

f.open("file.txt", fstream::trunc | fstream::out);

on windows in order to actually generate the file. Just doing trunc didn't work.