# File handling error

Tags: c++

I having 2 problem with file handling .

1. File(txt) is not creating using fstream.Here is my code

> ```
> #include<iostream>
> #include<conio.h>
> #include<fstream>
>
> void main()
> {char string[80];
>    int len;
>
> std::cout<<"Enter a string ";
>
> std::cin>>string;
>
>  len=strlen(string);
>
> std::fstream file;
>
> file.open("RO1.TXT",std::ios::out|std::ios::in);
>
> for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
>
> file.put(string[i]);
>
> file.seekg(0);
>
> char ch;
>
> while(file)
>
> {file.get(ch);
>
> std::cout<<ch;
>
> }
>   file.close();
> getch();
> }
> ```

The problem there is no file  is created of the name `RO1.TXT`
is my fstream corrupted?

2.If i build using ofstream and ifstream then file is creating but an extra character is being displayed
code

```
   #include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>

void main()
{std::ofstream file;
char string[80];
int len;
file.open("RO1.TXT");

std::cout<<"Enter a string ";
std::cin>>string;
 len=strlen(string);

for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    file.put(string[i]);
file.close();
std::ifstream file1;
file1.open("RO1.TXT");
char ch;
while(file1)
{file1.get(ch);
std::cout<<ch;
}
file1.close();
getch();
}
```

The problem is extra character is being displayed

Comment: Your indentation is horrendous! Please clean it up.

Comment: Your first example works for me, although I had to remove the `#include <conio.h>`, add `#include <cstring>` and remove the `getch();` at the bottom

Comment: @MsFreedom911 For the first example (as I wrote in my answer) remove the std::ios::in and see if it works

Comment: @asalic it is giving some ascii character

Comment: @ Tom Fenech.its giving same output

Comment: @MsFreedom911 I'm not sure I understand you. Does it create a file with a strange char in it?

Comment: @asalic.Thanks The file is created with right character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the ifstream is still valid when you read from it; You read and then display, but if the stream has ended... Try this:

```
std::ifstream file1;
file1.open("RO1.TXT");
char ch;
while(file1.good())
{
   file1.get(ch);
   if (file1.good())
    std::cout<<ch;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This may help you with the first problem:

[std::fstream doesn't create file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835888/stdfstream-doesnt-create-file)

You have to remove std::fstream::in from your mode argument, or specify std::fstream::trunc as it's said in the above link

Answer (score 2):

The last character is displayed twice because you are checking for file stream errors before reading from the file (i.e., before reading end-of-file). You need to check for an error *after* getting the character.

Comment: @MsFreedom911: Unfortunately lots of schools teach I/O loops wrong, and yours is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (file1)
{
    file1.get(ch);
    std::cout<<ch;
}
```

is wrong

```
while (file1.get(ch))
{
    std::cout<<ch;
}
```

is right.

Your version is wrong beceause it's only after you try to read and fail that `file1` becomes false. This is why you get a repeated character at the end of your file. You call `file.get` one more time than you have characters in the file but because you don't check for an error at the right place you also call `std::cout<<ch` one more time than you have characters in the file.

Sometimes seems that every single programmer in the world makes this mistake when they are starting out.

Comment: I think it's because apparently every school in the world makes this mistake when it is starting out and for twenty years thereafter.