# How to force C++ fstream create file without append mode?

Tags: c++, fstream

Fstream does not create file if it is not there unless it is opened in an append mode. Append mode however forbids overwriting the original data, and I want to be able to seekp and seekg anywhere inside.

Unlike question asked here: [std::fstream doesn't create file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835888/stdfstream-doesnt-create-file)
I have a requirements for it not be in either append or truncate mods and still be able to to seekg and seekp anywhere in thise file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::fstream doesn't create file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835888/stdfstream-doesnt-create-file)

Comment: no, unlike that question I need to seekg and seekp anywhere in file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little more work, but you could attempt to open the `fstream`, and if it fails open (and close) an output file stream (`ofstream`) which creates the file, and then try to reopen the `fstream`.