# Why doesn't std::fstream write to a file?

Tags: c++

I'm getting different behavior between `fstream` vs. `oftream` which I cannot explain.

When I use `fstream`, *nothing happens, i.e. no file is created*:

```
int main()
{
    std::fstream file("myfile.txt");
    file << "some text"  << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but when I change `fstream` to `oftream`, it works.

Why?

The second argument of `fstream` CTOR is `ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out` which makes me think that the file is opened in read-write mode, right?

Comment: That should work.  Buffering?  I think we need a complete [mcve].

Comment: I have just a function with this code and it does not work. I have nothing more to write. MVS2015.

Comment: Maybe you are checking too early if it wrote to your file, e.g. "close()" is only called on destroying the fstream

Comment: Did you check if it's open? Like in `if (!file) cout <<"Error";`. Have you tried with `std::ofstream file(...`?

Comment: OF COURSE you have more to write: those two lines won't compile.  You need at least one header file to define std::fstream and you need a `main` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::fstream doesn't create file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835888/stdfstream-doesnt-create-file)

Comment: A broad lesson to learn from here: always check for error after I/O operations.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`ios_base::in` requires the file to exist](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open).

If you provide **only** `ios_base::out`, only then will the file be created if it doesn't exist.

```
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| openmode           | Action if file already exists | Action if file does not exist |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| in                 | Read from start               | Failure to open               |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| out, out|trunc     | Destroy contents              | Create new                    |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| app, out|app       | Append to file                | Create new                    |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| out|in             | Read from start               | Error                         |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| out|in|trunc       | Destroy contents              | Create new                    |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| out|in|app, in|app | Write to end                  | Create new                    |
+--------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

---

**PS:**

Some basic error handling could also prove useful in understanding what's going on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::fstream file("triangle.txt");
  if (!file) {
    std::cerr << "file open failed: " << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
  file << "Some text " << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
 C:\temp> mytest.exe
 file open failed: No such file or directory

 C:\temp>
```