# c++ filestream problems when opening file in read write mode

Tags: c++, file-handling, filestreams

Consider the following code snippet:

```
const char * filePath = "C:/blah.mtt";
fstream fs(filePath, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
if (fs.fail())
   std::cout << "Failed to open the file!\n";
```

the fs.fail() check succeeds always. Does it mean that I can't open a file in both read write mode at the same time?

Creating an empty file first and then running the above code, fs.fail() is false always. What is the rational for such a behavior by the fstream class?

**Note:** I do have requisite permissions for creating the file. I am trying this on windows 10 using VS2015

Comment: Are you sure that Windows understands the forward slash in your path?

Comment: @Quentin I'm pretty sure that Windows is agnostic at such a thing that it can accept both forward and backward slashes.

Comment: @Neijwiert well, even some parts of explorer.exe choke on them, hence my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it mean that I can't open a file in both read write mode at the same time?

No, you can do this, but the question is whether you can *create* a file by doing so.

Generally you'll need to add the `trunc` flag (ironically one of the options for how to handle an existing file), or remove the `in` flag (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8836041/560648)).

Yes, this is a bit of a pain, but it comes from how the original POSIX APIs work. Blame them!

> Creating an empty file first and then running the above code, fs.fail() is false always. What is the rational for such a behavior by the fstream class?

You can always open a file that exists (well, subject to permissions). That behaviour makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> the fs.fail() check succeeds always. Does it mean that I can't open a file in both read write mode at the same time?

Refer to @Lightness Races in Orbit's answer for a better explanation.

> Creating an empty file first and then running the above code, fs.fail() is false always. What is the rational for such a behavior by the fstream class?

If you look at the [constructor definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/fstream/) of `fstream` you can see that `mode` defines the way you open it. It has other options like `app` to append to an existing file. If you open up a file using the following code:

```
fstream fs(filePath, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

You are saying create a new file if it doesn't exist. Which fails if you pre-created it. You should add the `app`, `ate` or `trunc`flag if you want it to open successfully. This depends on what exactly you want to do. However, do note that in between the steps of creating and then opening it doesn't guarantee that the file is still there. You should try to do it in one swoop and let exception handling do its work, since you can never go around the errors anyway.

Comment: I think I didn't explain it properly. Without creating an empty file first, the fstream object is always in error state (fs.fail() returns true)... but if I create an empty file first, then fstream object is in good state(fs.fail() returns false)...Isn't this opposite of you are saying...

Comment: @Arun: No, it's exactly what Neijwiert is saying. Although I don't think this is very clear

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are correct, I didn't correctly describe the meaning. Your answer better describes it. Should this question not be marked as duplicate as the post you refer to is pretty much the same?

Comment: @Neijwiert: Weeeeeeeeell maybe. I found it after I'd started writing and haven't the heart to close it now ^_^ I think we can get away with saying this question can be answered specifically as we need to dispel the misconception as well as give more general advice